# Framer Motion. Scope provided but no element detected error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I am creating a fun multiplayer game. The logic is simple. You create a game, you share the link or session ID with your opponent and he/she will join the game.

The tech stack is React, Next.js, Firabase's Cloudfire Store, and Framer Motion for animations.

I created a Loading component that shows up for a while when the first player clicks on the New Game button. The loading component shows up as long as the new game is created on the server. When the game is done, the page is redirected to a new page.

But after I end up on the new page, I get the below error.

[image]

I will add the source code to make the picture crystal clear.

### Loading.tsx

```js
    import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import { useAnimate } from "framer-motion";
    import { ImPlus as IconX } from "react-icons/im";
    import { BsRecordCircleFill as IconO } from "react-icons/bs";
    
    const X = 20;
    const DELAY = 0.3;
    const CHILD_ROTATION = 45;
    const CONTAINER_ROTATION = 180;
    
    const xSelector = "span:nth-child(1)";
    const oSelector = "span:nth-child(2)";
    
    const Loading = () => {
      const containerRotation = useRef(0);
      const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const animation = async () => {
          /* 1 */
          animate(
            xSelector,
            { x: [-X, 0], rotate: [-CHILD_ROTATION, 0] },
            { delay: DELAY }
          );
          await animate(oSelector, { x: [X, 0] }, { delay: DELAY });
    
          /* 2 */
          containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
          await animate(scope?.current, { rotate: containerRotation.current });
    
          /* 3 */
          animate(xSelector, { x: -X, rotate: [0, CHILD_ROTATION] });
          await animate(oSelector, { x: X });
    
          /* 4 */
          animate(xSelector, { x: 0, rotate: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });
          await animate(oSelector, { x: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });
    
          /* 5 */
          containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
          await animate(scope?.current, { rotate: containerRotation.current });
    
          /* 6 */
          animate(xSelector, { x: -X, rotate: -CHILD_ROTATION });
          await animate(oSelector, { x: X });
    
          animation();
        };
    
        animation();
      }, [scope, animate]);
    
      return (
        <div ref={scope} className="flex text-8xl text-indigo-900">
          <span className="-mr-1">
            <IconX />
          </span>
          <span className="-ml-1">
            <IconO />
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Loading;
```

### pages/index.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { createNewGame } from "@/utils/service";
import { Button, Viewport, Waterfall, Loading } from "@/components";
import { useAuth } from "@/utils/hooks";

export default function Home() {
  const [isGameLoading, setIsGameLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const playerId = useAuth();
  const [gameIdToJoin, setGameIdToJoin] = useState("");

  const clickHandler = async () => {
    setIsGameLoading(true);
    if (playerId) {
      const gameId = await createNewGame(playerId);
      router.push(`/${gameId}`);
    }
  };

  const joinToGame = () => {
    router.push(`/${gameIdToJoin}`);
  };

  return (
    <Viewport>
      {isGameLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-5 z-10">
            <Button onClick={clickHandler} className="rounded-xl">
              Create a New Game
            </Button>
            <p className="text-4xl">or join to a game</p>
            <p className="relative">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Game id here"
                className="bg-indigo-100 p-4 text-indigo-900 text-2xl rounded-l-lg placeholder:text-indigo-900/50 placeholder:italic focus:ring-2 ring-inset ring-indigo-900 outline-none"
                value={gameIdToJoin}
                onChange={(e) => setGameIdToJoin(e.target.value)}
              />
              <Button className="rounded-r-lg" onClick={joinToGame}>
                Join
              </Button>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="absolute">
            <Waterfall>O X</Waterfall>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </Viewport>
  );
}
```

### pages/[gameId].tsx

```js
import { useEffect, FC } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { GetServerSideProps, GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next";
import { readGameData } from "@/utils/service";
import { GameData, PlayersData, ReadGameData } from "@/utils/types";
import { useAuth } from "@/utils/hooks";
import { Board } from "@/components";

interface Props {
  data: GameData & PlayersData;
  gameId: string;
  isLoaded: boolean;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext
) => {
  const { gameId } = context.query;
  const { isLoaded, data }: ReadGameData = await readGameData(gameId as string);

  return {
    props: {
      isLoaded,
      gameId: gameId as string,
      data: data as GameData & PlayersData,
    },
  };
};

const Page: FC<Props> = ({ data, gameId, isLoaded }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const playerId = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      router.push("/404");
    }
  }, [isLoaded, router]);

  if (!playerId) return null;

  return <Board data={data} playerId={playerId} gameId={gameId} />;
};

export default Page;
```

So, this is all files you should see. What I am missing here? Since the Loading component is not part of the gameId page, why does this become a problem when I create a new game? BTW, if I reload the gameId page, the problem will be gone which is interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Use animate function only if scope is present in the view

```js
if(scope.current) {
   animate(
        xSelector,
        { x: [-X, 0], rotate: [-CHILD_ROTATION, 0] },
        { delay: DELAY }
      );
      await animate(oSelector, { x: [X, 0] }, { delay: DELAY });

      /* 2 */
      containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
      await animate(scope?.current, { rotate: containerRotation.current });

      /* 3 */
      animate(xSelector, { x: -X, rotate: [0, CHILD_ROTATION] });
      await animate(oSelector, { x: X });

      /* 4 */
      animate(xSelector, { x: 0, rotate: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });
      await animate(oSelector, { x: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });

      /* 5 */
      containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
      await animate(scope?.current, { rotate: containerRotation.current });

      /* 6 */
      animate(xSelector, { x: -X, rotate: -CHILD_ROTATION });
      await animate(oSelector, { x: X });
}
```

Comment: This is a fact. I solved the issue by checking the scope before every usage of animate since the animation function is running async.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Let me explain to you.

The first fact is animation is created for a spinning loading component. When the page load is done, the component no longer will be on DOM. And, this component is the scope of the animation.

Another fact, the animation function runs async. This means while it is triggered it will try to finish its job.

The problem is when the page loaded loading component will not be there and the scope of animation will be gone.

To prevent the issue, I checked the scope of every stage of animation. In this way, I make sure that the scope is still there and ready to animate.

I know it looks complex but you will get it if you see the code.

```
  const xSelector = "span:nth-child(1)";
  const oSelector = "span:nth-child(2)";

  const checkSelectors = () => {
    return (
      document.querySelector(xSelector) && document.querySelector(oSelector)
    );
  };

  const animation = async () => {
    if (scope?.current && checkSelectors()) {
      // 1
      animate(
        xSelector,
        { x: [-X, 0], rotate: [-CHILD_ROTATION, 0] },
        { delay: DELAY }
      );
      await animate(oSelector, { x: [X, 0] }, { delay: DELAY });

      if (scope?.current) {
        // 2
        containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
        await animate(scope?.current, {
          rotate: containerRotation.current,
        });
      }

      if (scope?.current && checkSelectors()) {
        // 3
        animate(xSelector, {
          x: -X,
          rotate: [0, CHILD_ROTATION],
        });
        await animate(oSelector, { x: X });
      }

      if (scope?.current && checkSelectors()) {
        // 4
        animate(xSelector, { x: 0, rotate: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });
        await animate(oSelector, { x: 0 }, { delay: DELAY });
      }

      if (scope?.current) {
        // 5
        containerRotation.current += CONTAINER_ROTATION;
        await animate(scope?.current, {
          rotate: containerRotation.current,
        });
      }

      if (scope?.current && checkSelectors()) {
        // 6
        animate(xSelector, { x: -X, rotate: -CHILD_ROTATION });
        await animate(oSelector, { x: X });
      }

      animation();
    }
  };
```